# How do I limit the dynamically created views to 10?

Tags: java, android, view, tablelayout, tablerow

I am dynamically adding rows to a table layout.I want to restrict the views to 10 views i.e display only 10 rows.

`OnClick` I call a method called `showItem()`.

```
    private void showItem(String json) {
    String itembarcode = "";
    String itemdesc = "";
    String weight = "";
    String rate = "";
    String making = "";
    String netrate = "";
    String total = "";


    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ParseBarcode.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject itemData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        itembarcode = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_BARCODE);
        itemdesc = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_DESC);
        weight = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_WEIGHT);
        rate = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_RATE);
        making = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_MAKING);
        netrate = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_NETRATE);
        total = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_TOTAL);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //table started

    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    rowParams.setMargins(16, 0, 16, 0);

    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(AddInvEst.this);
    tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

    TableRow newRow = new TableRow(AddInvEst.this);
    newRow.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

    barCode = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    barCode.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    barCode.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    itemDesc = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    itemDesc.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    itemDesc.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    weightLine = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    weightLine.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.75f));
    weightLine.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    rateAmount = new EditText(AddInvEst.this);
    rateAmount.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
    rateAmount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    rateAmount.addTextChangedListener(rateTextWatcher);

    makingAmount = new EditText(AddInvEst.this);
    makingAmount.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
    makingAmount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    makingAmount.addTextChangedListener(mkAmountTextWatcher);

    netRate = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    netRate.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
    netRate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    netrates.add(netrate);

    itemtotal = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    itemtotal.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    itemtotal.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    totals.add(total);

    double[] doubleList = new double[totals.size()];
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totals.size(); ++i) {
        doubleList[i] = Double.parseDouble(totals.get(i));
        sum += doubleList[i];
    }

    barCode.setText(itembarcode);
    itemDesc.setText(itemdesc);
    weightLine.setText(weight);
    rateAmount.setText(rate);
    makingAmount.setText(making);
    netRate.setText(netrate);
    itemtotal.setText(total);
    textViewSum.setText(sum * (0.02) + sum + "");//set total text to sum
    textViewVat.setText(sum * (0.02) + "");

    newRow.addView(barCode);
    newRow.addView(itemDesc);
    newRow.addView(weightLine);
    newRow.addView(rateAmount);
    newRow.addView(makingAmount);
    newRow.addView(netRate);
    newRow.addView(itemtotal);
    itemTable.addView(newRow);
}
```

Right now `onClick` I inflate one row (view). I don't want the user to inflate the view more than 10 times.But every time the button is clicked only one row (view) is inflated.

Comment: You want 10 results on one click, or one result per click up to 10 clicks?

Comment: @mjp66 one result per click up to 10 clicks

Comment: OK, then just set up a counter (int counter = 0) and for each onClick() advance the counter value, and check the counter value before executing your action... if it's <= 10, call showItem(), otherwise do nothing.

Comment: @mjp66 can you give a example I am new to programming.Thanks

Comment: @ArthurKorchagin just checked your profile can you please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int count = 0;
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (count++ < 10) {
            showItem();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mjp66 :)

Comment: Welcome and happy programming ;)